# update decimal field using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have a problem of updating the decimal field in my project
this is my view

```
 <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="colFormLabelLg" name="rate" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">rate</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input  value="{{$rate}}" class="form-control form-control-lg" >
                    </div>
                </div>
```

i'm passing the data from the edit view like this

```
 public function edit($id)
{$terminal = terminal::find($id);
$rate = $terminal->rate;
return view('terminal.editTerminal',compact('terminal','rate'));}
```

the update function

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    terminal::find($id)->update($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('terminal.index');
}
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: then `$rate` needs to be `float` inside the migration

Comment: you mean i have to change the data type  in database into float? @ChristianGallarmin

Comment: Well, what data type is it currently? If it's an integer, the reason for your issue should be pretty clear.

Comment: the data type is decimal @ceejayoz

Comment: OK, that should work fine. Can you be more specific on what you mean by "a problem"? Is it not showing up in the form right? Are updates to the field not saving?

Comment: it  doesn't save the updates @ceejayoz

Comment: @hala Show us the code where you process and save the updates, then.

Comment: see the updates to the question up @ceejayoz

Comment: @hala OK, now it's time to do some debugging. `dd(terminal::find($id))` to make sure it actually found the Terminal model you're looking for. Then `dd($request->all())` to make sure the data is being sent correctly. Then check the Terminal model to see if `rate` is [a `$fillable` item](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#mass-assignment).

Comment: i did the debuging in the first one it shows the model perfectly and in the second debug it shows true @ceejayoz

Comment: You get `true` for `$request->all()`? That's not right.

Comment: what should i do ? @ceejayoz and what does true mean??

Comment: Your `<input>` element doesn't have a name attribute

Comment: Your question is just a bulk of code. Next time explai what's happening. Check your fillable on your model.

Comment: thank you @user3647971 i was putting the name in the label instead of the input  my fault